# xquery using fn:count function on sequence

Tags: xquery

I am updating a file that returns a sequence of figure elements from a search. The count function works just fine to count the total number of items returned:

```
let $total-count := fn:count($result)
```

However, I also need to count the number of figure elements that contain video elements as well as those that contain graphic elements, but these statements do not work:

```
let $vid-count := fn:count($result//video)
let $graph-count := fn:count($result//graphic)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're counting the video (respective graphic) elements contained *inside* all `$result` elements. If you want to count elements which contain another element, use predicates instead of axis steps.

```
let $vid-count := fn:count($result[.//video])
let $graph-count := fn:count($result[.//graphic])
```

Comment: Well, I thought it might involve using a predicate, but could not divine what it would be. The above statements are not working either. Sure seems like they should.

Comment: Give some small, but comprehensible example input and also expected output. Especially make sure to include all namespace declarations if there are any, in case you're unsure post a larger example document on eg. [gist](http://gist.github.com).